# Как создать для каждого модуля по одной dll в Microsoft Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, модули

У меня есть проект в нем 6 файлов. При сборке через настройки visual studio создаётся только одна dll. Хотелось бы иметь на каждый файл по одной dll, то есть реализовать систему плагинов.

Вопрос:Как создать для каждого модуля по одной dll  в Microsoft Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Ну создавайте 6 проектов по одному файлу в каждом...

Comment: Зачем мне 6 проектов, если на каждый модуль должно быть по одной dll.

Comment: 1 проект -> 1 артефакт сборки, dll в данном случае

Comment: Это всегда так будет, по другому никак?

Comment: Извратиться как-нибудь всегда можно, но зачем? Чем вам не нравится несколько проектов? При нормальной разработке вам наверное понадобится не меньше 3 проектов на каждую dll - проект с кодом (статическая или заголовочная библиотека), проект собираемый в dll, проект с тестами собираемый в exe. То бишь 6x3 = 18 проектов.